# How to get/set the "watched" status via Kodi's API?

Tags: json-rpc, kodi

I'm trying to write a lightweight wrapper on top of Kodi's JSON-RPC API ([v10](https://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API/v10)) using Python.  I'm using the (so far very helpful) [kodi-json](https://pypi.org/project/kodi-json/) module to do pretty much everything I need.  For example, this will give me the `title`, `position`, and `total` (run time) for all episodes for tv show ID `111`:

```py
kodi.VideoLibrary.GetEpisodes(tvshowid=111, properties=["title", "resume"])
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to get (let alone set) the "watched" status of any episode or movie in the system.  I know that it has to be there, since the normal UI I use on my Android set-top-box shows a little check mark next to all shows in a list.

The list of values I can pass to `properties` is long, but even when I specify every last one of the properties and print them all out, I can see no discernible difference between a show shown to be watched in the UI and one that isn't.  Similarly, I have the same problem when using the `GetEpisodeDetails` call.  I must be missing something.

Also note that there's no means for the user to see the UI, so the `InputAction` endpoints don't work for me either :-(

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it, but `playcount` appears to be the property I'm looking for, and it's right there in the list of available properties:

```py
kodi.VideoLibrary.GetEpisodes(tvshowid=111, properties=["title", "playcount"])
```

Even though it's called a `count`, it doesn't appear to increment with every time the video is played, but rather it's treated more like a boolean, `1` meaning "watched" and `0` meaning "unwatched".